# What's the standard way to interpret $Av \geq v$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

If $A$ is a matrix and $v$ is a vector, and one writes $Av \geq v$, what does this usually mean? Each coordinate is $\geq$?

Comment: Could be lexicographic order....It would be unusual for an author to write this without explanation.  I expect that the context explains what is intended.

Comment: maybe it refers to the norm

Comment: What context did you see this in?

Comment: I have seen $v\ge0$ in linear programming mean all components of $v$ are positive, which would lend itself to your interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

In linear programming, we usually use a matrix $A$ to represent the coefficients of a collection of variables $x$, and let $b$ denote the right-hand-side vector, with the inequality symbol to denote the connection between the $A$ matrix and vector $b$. For example:

Let $Ax \le b$ where $x \in \Bbb R^n$, $A \in \Bbb R^{m\times n}$, $b \in \Bbb R^{m}$, and $m,n \in \Bbb Z^{+}$.

Then we can represent a system of equations as $Ax \le b$ with the following:

$$a_{11}x_{1}+ a_{12}x_{2} + \cdots +a_{1n}x_{n} \le b_1$$
$$\vdots$$
$$a_{m1}x_{1}+ a_{m2}x_{2} + \cdots +a_{mn}x_{n} \le b_m$$

Thus, for the example you’ve provided $Av \ge v$, it would be the following:

$$a_{11}v_1 + a_{12}v_2 + \cdots + a_{1n}v_n \ge v_1$$
$$\vdots$$
$$a_{n1}v_1 + a_{n2}v_2 + \cdots + a_{nn}v_n \ge v_n$$